# MacOS BigSur and STS 4.8.1 refresh screen issue

Tags: spring-tools-4

As soon as I upgraded to BigSur 11.0.1, I started noticing that some of the UI components in STS 4.8.1 started to disappear (or let's say they don't show up, since as soon as I click in the area, where they are supposed to be located, they start to appear) - this can be observed in the History tab for example. Another issue appears during the Debugging - as soon the execution reaches any breakpoint the screen doesn't seem to be refreshed automatically and the current code line, where the breakpoint is, gets mixed with the previous code lines. EDIT: if I scroll the page (up/down) the screen gets refreshed and I am able to see the correct line.

Initially I thought that this could be due to the DevStyle plugin (the dark mode), but I uninstalled it completely and I tried again and the issues are still present.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few fixes being implemented at the moment inside of the Eclipse platform to fix issues with Big Sur. We plan to ship a new release of the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse as soon as the new Eclipse release is being available.

Please also feel free to raise issues at https://bugs.eclipse.org/ for the things that you observe on Big Sur.

Comment: You can also grab the latest CI builds of STS 4.9.0 on early Eclipse 4.18 pieces from here: http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html - I tried the latest on Eclipse 4.18 and it seems to work okay on macOS 11 BigSur (trying on the latest BigSure 11.1 Beta, although not sure if that makes a difference or not).

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the issues are solved with the latest STS 4.9.0 release.